# QGIS: Coordinate reference system

Tags: qgis

I want to use the buffer tool in QGIS with the distance in metres instead of degrees.

Which coordinate system is appropriate for Africa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use something along these lines:

WGS projected UTM coordinates
[image: WGS projected UTM coordinates]

But find the zone you want here:

UTM Grid zones
[image: UTM Grid zones]